# How do I set property name to variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I am working on an online class, for which we have to build a list tracker application using react. I have had issues when trying to set the state of one of my classes. In this state I have a variable which is equal to an object. I am attempting to variably set both the name and value of this object, however I was uncertain on how to set the name variably.

```
let name = this.props.idName;
this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {
        newItem: { name: item}
    };
}, () => {
this.props.addItem(this.state)
});
```

As you can see, I try to set the key in this object equal to the variable `name`, however this just sets it to the value of `name` rather than the value of the the `name` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this. Just enclose the name in square brackets. More on this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names.

```
let name = this.props.idName;
this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {
        newItem: { [name]: item}
    };
}, () => {
this.props.addItem(this.state)
});
```

```js
var k = "key";

var obj = {[k]: "VALUE"}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Link to the docs for computed properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Answer (score 0):

You can regard objects as dictionaries:

```
$ node
> let name = 'Nyan'
undefined
> let omg = { newItem: {} }
undefined
> omg
{ newItem: {} }
> omg['newItem'][name] = 'item' // note the quotes in this statement
'item'
> omg
{ newItem: { Nyan: 'item' } }
```